# Just using Angular to show a message

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so i've been trying to learn angular for the past couple of days and i've set this up so that a message comes up...but it seems like its not working and i cannot figure out why. Please let me know if its just a misspell or something been looking at it for hours now... THanks

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>My Routing App!</title>

    <!-- set the base path for angular routing -->
    <base href="/">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\JChoi\Desktop\font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.css">
    <style>
        body { padding-top:50px; }
    </style>

    <!-- JS -->
    <!-- load angular and angular-route via CDN -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <!-- load our custom angular app files -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.routes.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container" ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="mainController as main">

    <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
    <main>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>{{ main.bigMessage }}</h1>
        </div>

        <!-- angular templating will go here -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    </main>

</body>
</html>
```

JS/Angular code:

```
angular.module('routerApp', ['routerRoutes'])

// create the controller and inject Angular's 
// this will be the controller for the ENTIRE site
.controller('mainController', function() {

    var vm = this;

        // create a bigMessage variable to display in our view
        vm.bigMessage = 'A smooth sea never made a skilled sailor.';

})

// home page specific controller
.controller('homeController', function() {

    var vm = this;

    vm.message = 'This is the home page!';
})

// about page controller
.controller('aboutController', function() {

    var vm = this;

        vm.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
})

// contact page controller
.controller('contactController', function() {

    var vm = this;

        vm.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

Here is a codepen link as well:
http://codepen.io/zomdar/pen/doPJgY?editors=101

Comment: You don't list `ngRoute` as a module dependency at `angular.module('routerApp', ['routerRoutes'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please change `routerRoutes` to `ngRoute` in your model settings.

Write this code

```
angular.module('routerApp', ['ngRoute'])
```

instead of this code

```
angular.module('routerApp', ['routerRoutes'])
```

### [Working Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGbpMK)

### Explanation for your error

You have call this(`angular-route.js`) script in your screen

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js"></script>
```

You can see the details about that script  from : http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular-route.js

The defined route module by `ngRoute' Name.

see

```
 angular.module('ngRoute', ['ng']).
                        provider('$route', $RouteProvider),
```

**So you should be call `ngRoute` in you main module.**

Comment: it works in codepen but is there a reason when i do it on my desktop it still doesnt work?

Comment: @jeremy  Clear your browser history and try to force refresh your browser :)

Comment: I'm not sure why but its still not working on my desktop i tried clearing hte browser history as well as force refreshing

Comment: nvm i just fixed it...sometypos

Answer (score 0):

The codepen link is broken because you didn't add the "routerRoutes" module. If you remove it, the sample is working.

Do you have content in your "app.routes.js" file?